# Reducing a system of Linear Recurrences

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, oeis

The number of ways to lay unit-length matchsticks on a $2 \times n$ grid (with respect to vertices) appears to be given by [OEIS sequence A093129](https://oeis.org/A093129), but I found it a different way, and I'm looking for insight into how to move from one to the other.

In particular, it looks like $A093129(n) = a_1(n + 1) + a_5(n + 1)$ where

$$
\begin{align}
a_1(n+1) &= a_1(n) + a_5(n)\\
a_2(n+1) &= a_1(n) + a_2(n) + 2a_5(n) + a_6(n) + a_7(n)\\
a_3(n+1) &= a_3(n) + a_5(n) + a_6(n)\\
a_4(n+1) &= a_4(n) + a_5(n) + a_6(n)\\
a_5(n+1) &= a_2(n) + a_5(n) + a_6(n) + a_7(n) \\
a_6(n+1) &= a_3(n) + a_5(n) + a_7(n)\\
a_7(n+1) &= a_4(n) + a_5(n) + a_6(n)
\end{align}
$$
with initial conditions $$
  a_1(0) = a_2(0) = 1\\
  a_3(0) = ... = a_7(0) = 0.
$$

In particular, it appears that $$
\begin{align}
a_1(n + 1) + a_5(n + 1) &= (a_1 + a_5)(n + 1) \\
  &= A093129(n)\\
  &= 5\cdot(A093129(n - 1) + A093129(n - 2))\\
  &= 5\cdot((a_1 + a_5)(n) - (a_1 + a_5)(n - 1)).
\end{align}
$$

---

## Questions

1. How does one prove this recursion?
2. Is there a general strategy for transforming such "systems of linear recurrences" to a single linear recurrence? (Can this even be done in general?)

---

## An Idea

One thing that I try is to write this as $$
  (a_1 + a_5)(n) = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
  \end{bmatrix}^T
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}^n
  \begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
  \end{bmatrix}
$$ and do some linear algebra trickery to see if I can come up with some sort of closed form—but in this case, I'm really more interested in getting a recurrence.

Comment: `transforming such "systems of linear recurrences" to a single linear recurrence` See a (very) simple example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2640564/291201). Using the same technique repeatedly, variables can be eliminated one at a time until you get a single linear recurrence. The same could be achieved with matrix manipulations, I guess, though in your case the calculations don't look too pretty either way.

Comment: Here is another question I asked related to the above example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764265/121988.