# Explaining recurrence for number of no-leaf subgraphs in $2 \times n$ grid.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, combinatorial-geometry

Consider the number of leaf-free subgraphs of the $2 \times n$ grid—which is to say, the number of ways to draw lines on the $2 \times n$ grid such that no grid point has degree exactly 1.

---

For example, when $n = 4$ there are $15$ such subgraphs:
[image: Fifteen 2 by 4 leaf free subgraphs.]

---

The number of leaf-free subgraphs of the $2 \times n$ grid is [given by the linear recurrence](https://oeis.org/A020876)

> $a(1) = 1$
>
> $a(2) = 2$
>
> $a(n+1) = 5\left(a(n) - a(n-1)\right)$.

What is a combinatorial explanation for this recurrence?

Comment: You're asking for the number of length-$n$ strings belonging to a certain regular language, which explains why there *is* a linear recurrence.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding you, but I'm asking for a combinatorial explanation for this *particular* recurrence. I have some intuition for why the number of these grids is some linear recurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question on Reddit, and user bairedota [posted a response](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/8gnsas/math_stack_exchange_counting_subgraphs_in_the_2n/dydc3ky/) that effectively solved the problem.

The idea: We start with a subset of generation $n$ and we build to generation $n+1$.

1. First, remove all subgraphs that do not have a vertical edge at the rightmost position. There are $a(n) - a(n-1)$ such graphs, because we subtract out those in the previous generation that are extended by a "blank":
   [image]
2. To each of these, we construct five children. Three "generic" children, and two children that depend on the shape of the parent.

   i) Extend by a blank:

   [image: extend by a blank]

   ii) Extend by a full square:

   [image: extend by square]

   iii) Extend by a square as above, but delete the vertical edge:

   [image: Square minus edge]

   iv) Special case 1:

   [image]

   v) Special case 2:

   [image]

---

Since this creates $5(a(n) - a(n-1))$ distinct leaf-free figures, this enumerates all possible leaf-free subgraphs of the $2 \times (n+1)$ grid.