# Bijection between leaf-free subgraphs of the Möbius ladder and the ladder graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are the same number of leaf-free<sup>1</sup> subgraphs on the [ladder graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_graph) $L_{n+2}$ and on the [Möbius ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_ladder)<sup>2</sup> $M_n$, which is given by OEIS sequence [A020876](https://oeis.org/A020876). Furthermore, these graphs have a very similar structure<sup>3</sup>.

I'm looking for a bijection that respects that structure. In particular, I feel like the two subgraphs with no edges should map to each other, and the two subgraphs with all of the edges should map to each other.

---

#### Example

For example, when $n = 2$ there are $15$ leaf-free subgraphs of $M_2$ 
[image]
and $15$ leaf-free subgraphs of $L_{4}$:
[image: Fifteen 2 by 4 leaf free subgraphs.]

---

<sup>1</sup> A leaf-free subgraph is a subgraph with no vertex has degree exactly one.

<sup>2</sup>The Wikipedia article uses a different convention from the OEIS sequence. I use the OEIS convention: $M_n$ has $2n$ vertices.

<sup>3</sup>You can think of the relationship between $M_{n}$ and $L_{n+2}$ as being analogous to the relationship between a rectangle and the Möbius strip made from that rectangle, by identifying the ends with a twist.

Comment: See if you can show the recurrence relation $a_n=5(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})$ for both types of objects. This may shed some light on how to establish your required bijection.

Comment: The only bijective proof of the recurrence relation that I know is for the grid graph and is somewhat contrived: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764265/121988